# I've installed Ubuntu et Grub on the root partition, but don't know how to boot on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, windows

I have installed Ubuntu like that (next to Windows) :

- root partition
- swap partition
- home partition
- mount point on root partition

I want to display the Windows boot menu at startup, but I don't know how to add the Ubuntu entry. I can't use EasyBCD because I have UEFI bios. Can you tell me how to add Ubuntu to the Windows boot menu please?
I watched this tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iSAyiicyQY

Comment: Is this a dual boot system, if so did you read up on how to dual boot?

Comment: yes it is a dual boot system (next to Windows 10). I watched this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iSAyiicyQY) and the guy is using easyBCD; but I can't...

Comment: And what does the official Ubuntu doc say on how to dual boot?

Comment: they are telling me to reset my computer and use Legacy bios instead of UEFI... I don't want that

Comment: Perhaps that is the best configuration for your situation... Is your system UEFI  compliant?

Comment: I really don't want to reset my computer. I would be too long and complicated...

Comment: Does the EFI boot menu (some key at power-up to allow you to select a boot device/OS) allow you to select ubuntu/grub?

Comment: @ubfan1 i can only select Windows 10